# UIScroll View set initial image size less than full size

Tags: ios, swift

This view loads just one image and allows the user to zoom in and out to view parts of the image up close. However, it loads at a gigantic size, and I want it to load at screen size. Or if screen size is hard to get, then just loading at 50% size would work.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1
    self.scrollView.delegate = self
    self.imageView.image = self.image!
    }

    func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return self.imageView
    }
}
```

How do I set the initial image size to a reasonable size, but allow for zooming to the full size image?

Thanks!

Comment: scrollView.zoomScale = view.frame.width  / imageView.image.size.width

Comment: Adding `scrollView.zoomScale = view.frame.width / imageView.image.size.width` within viewDidLoad doesn't seem to have any effect on the size of the image upon loading. @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: Did you try adding it bellow imageView.image = image! ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to calculate the zoom dividing your view width by your image size width as follow:

```
scrollView.zoomScale = view.frame.width / imageView.image.size.width
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the screen size: (objective-C)

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
let screenWidth = screenSize.width
let screenHeight = screenSize.height
```

Set the UIImageView frame to the screen size, and then set the aspect to fit:

```
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit (UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit in Obj-C)
```

Then, just set the zoomScale:

```
self.scrollView.zoomScale = .5;
```

Comment: I'm new at this, so apologies if I am not understanding. I added the following code within the viewDidLoad and it had no effect on the size of the image upon loading.

        `let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        let screenWidth = screenSize.width
        let screenHeight = screenSize.height
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        self.scrollView.zoomScale = 0.5;`